# Pegar parâmetro da url com $_GET vindo de um iframe - WORDPRESS

Tags: php, wordpress, get, iframe

Estou com uma dificuldade, dentro do meu site coloquei um `iframe` que tem um botão que direciona pra outra pagina dentro do meu site via `GET`.

só que esse botão já vai pre setado.

ex.:

O link que tem dentro do iframe vai para http://www.meusite.com.br/Detalhes.php?id=17936

Penso eu que tenho que criar uma pagina com o mesmo nome Detalhes e dentro dele colocar a função `$_GET['id']`;

Usei até um plugin que lê php, e nada..

Eu coloquei um iframe dentro do meu site vindo de outro servidor
segue o site http://www.grupodisnave.com.br/seminovos/ e quando clico em mais detalhes o link vai pra outra pagina com o id na URL só que no wordpress não me permite usar o GET

Alguém tem ideia do que deve ser feito?

Comment: Podes [edit] a pergunta e explicar melhor "botão que direciona pra outra pagina dentro do meu site"? Queres abrir essa nova página dentro da iFrame? não serve somente com uma ancora?

Comment: Quer enviar algum parâmetro para um IFRAME com o método GET?? Ou vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

Você deverá "enganar" o wordpress, uma vez que ao passar parâmetros por url você receba o erro `404 Not Found`.
Crie este simples plugin no seu **functions.php:**

```
<?php

add_filter('query_vars', 'parameter_queryvars' );
function parameter_queryvars( $qvars )
{
$qvars[] = 'id';
return $qvars;
}
?>
```

AQUI ESTÁ A CONDICIONAL PARA OBTER O VALOR DO ID

```
global $wp_query;
if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['id'])){
print $wp_query->query_vars['id'];

//código aqui, da página
}
```

Comment: Ajudou? Marque como positivo. Abraço.

Comment: Obrigado Lollipop pela resposta rápida. 

Eu coloquei um iframe dentro do meu site vindo de outro servidor http://www.grupodisnave.com.br/seminovos/ e quando clico em mais detalhes o link vai pra outra pagina com o id na URL só que no wordpress não me permite usar o GET

Comment: Então você quer receber um GET, vindo de um iframe, do seu próprio site?

Comment: DIGA-ME: `Site 1` - possui o iframe
`Site 2` - o seu wordpress que tem o iframe do site 1

`Ação:` clicar em + detalhes e ser direcionado pra onde? SITE 1 OU 2?

Comment: direciona pra outra pagina no site 1 http://www.grupodisnave.com.br/seminovos/

Comment: Espera..........

Comment: editado, gabriel

Comment: Continua dando pagina não encontrada..

Comment: Utilizou o `if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['id'])){` como ?

Comment: Criei um pagina no wordpress com o mesmo nome dado no link, coloquei o codigo dentro do post com esse plugin "PHP Code for Posts and Pages"

<iframe id="iframe" width="100%" height="1000px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://gerenciador.publinkrio.net/client/detalhesveiculo.aspx?id=<?php
global $wp_query;
if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['id'])){
print $wp_query->query_vars['id'];
}
?>&cliente=204&backcolor=FFFFFF&backcolorbutton=C40001">

Comment: `1 -` Vai em configurações, links permanentes e salve as configurações. `2 -` Você tem que desistir do que falei, pois você não disse que criou uma página em wordpress, pensei que era um minhapagina.php, dentro do tema. `3 -` Configure os Links Permanentes e sempre salve.

Comment: Desculpa não entendi.. é pra eu retirar o código que me passou ?

Comment: Você está com 2 problemas, meu amigo:` 1 -` Se você criou uma página pelo admin do wordpress, e não está aparecendo, é porque você precisa atualizar os links permanentes. `2 -` E quando der certo, caso você esteja querendo pegar o valor do `id` pelo page.php, você deve fazer o que lhe instrui sobre `if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['id']))`


Explique-me a estrutura dessas páginas que voce criou em wordpress. SE NÃO FOR ISSO QUE DISSE.

Comment: É um sistema de carros vindo de fora, outro servidor, eles me forneceram um iframe para por no meu site, meu site foi todo desenvolvido em wordpress, a pagina de seminovos que vem desse sistema externo vem via iframe ou soap, o iframe coloquei na minha pagina.. até ai tudo ok.. o problema é que o sistema deles quando clico em mais detalhes ele vai teoricamente para uma outra pagina no meu site com o id na URL referente a aquele carro. só que meus links estão configurados com permalink não permitindo a url que o iframe gera sendo assim não estou conseguindo usar a função GET p pegar o ID da URL

Comment: Você criou essas páginan pelo admin do wordpress??

Comment: Isso pelo admin e coloquei o código php dentro do post via plugin

Comment: vamos para o bate papo

Comment: add meu gmail, ja que nao pode ir pro bate papo: rafaelmp.web@gmail.com